# Laptop with out backdoors and vulnerabilities?

Tags: laptop, security

I would like to buy a new laptop now.

Privacy and security is my priority.

I would like to know if there is already proven backdoors and vulnerabilities of top brands and manufacturers of laptops, cpu processors, memory etc. For example at other my question here (https://superuser.com/questions/1358405/vulnerabilities-of-it-system-due-to-hardware) someone told me that Lenovo and HP have preinstalled some vulnerabilities in their hardware.

So I would omit hardware of manufacturers who already got caught red handed for backdoors as well as omit hardware which is very sensitive in case of malicious software running around internet. In other words I need hardware which is safe from abuse of manufacturer as well as safe against viruses of 3rd party.

Probably there is no such an ideal hardware but please let know which brands to omit surely and which one are known to be safe and respecting privacy.

Are Dell or Asus trustable ?

Comment: This can help provide you with information in order to develop a better idea of what you want: https://www.fsf.org/resources/hw Otherwise, this is pretty broad and is asking for a list which is off-topic.

Comment: I feel like backdoor and vulnerabilities are more of an OS level concern than a hardware concern, unless you count something like [Meltdown or Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/) which, by the standards specified in your question, would disqualify all Intel Cpu's and products.

Comment: Also your question is a bit broad in it's current, state. Could you try and focus down specific requirements so we can better recommend you a certain laptop?

Comment: So, you're looking for something without TrustZone https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/security or the equivalent for other CPU manufacturers?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths thanks a lot, it seems this is something I was looking for

Comment: @Benett Yeo that is sad but right, however I heard is same for AMD, so there is no CPU with no backdoor ? what a pitty.. - specifying my question I try to set up most privacy oriented environement as I can, I have thought about software and OS, but now looking for hardware to not lost my effort - I need laptop which I can trust there is no backdoor for 3rd parties as well as authorities and is hard to compromise by an attacker

Comment: @ K7AAY without ? they call it is for security, but I guess AMD is not trustable as well ?

Comment: Most laptops vendors ship with Lojack, so if you really want to be secure that is going to be hard. (See today update on https://www.tomshardware.com/news/lojack-firmwre-enables-first-uefi-rootkit,37867.html)